# I am trying to save information to two data tables using one service method using c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

Writing an app and I am trying to add on to the method where a user creates a new gift card.  I added another column in my applicationuser table called TotalBalance that adds in the balances of each cards created.  So I can get a new card to save to the gift card table but I want the gift card balance to be added to the 'Users total donation balance' in the application user table.  The code I'm working with is below.

```
 public bool CreateGiftCard(GiftCardCreateViewModel model)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var company = context
                            .Company
                            .Where(e => e.CompanyName == model.CompanyName)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

            var companyId = company.CompanyId;

            var entity =
                        new GiftCard()
                        {
                            OwnerId = _userId,
                            Amount = model.Amount,
                            CardNumber = model.CardNumber,
                            DonationUtc = DateTime.Now,
                            CompanyId = companyId,

                            //  Optional 
                            ExpirationDate = model.ExpirationDate,
                            AccessNumber = model.AccessNumber
                        };

            company.CompanyAmount = company.CompanyAmount + entity.Amount;

            context.GiftCard.Add(entity);
            return context.SaveChanges() == 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be doing this in entirely the wrong place. Rather than handling it in the application at the time of update, you could look at creating this as a calculated column in the database itself.

The details will depend upon which RDBMS you're using, you might like to add a tag to indicate this.

To more directly answer your question, it is not possible to update two tables in a single select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your method (I guessed at some of the attribute names, but you can get the idea):

```
var appuser = context
                        .ApplicationUser
                        .Where(e => e.UserId == _userId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

appuser.TotalBalance += model.Amount;

context.ApplicationUser.Update(appuser);
```